# Is there a limit to the number of activities that a case can have on the wall?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

Is there any limit to the number of  activities in the  conversation tab (social pane or whatever it is called)?
If there will be large number of activities will it affect performance?

Note: CRM 2015 online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well yes performance will be effected, but I don't think it would cause a problem. Microsoft have implemented paging on all views and I expect this would be the same - probably worth confirming that however.

Comment: Thanks James, I assumed so. Does that imply that there is no limit to the number of activities that can be shown in the conversation tab.

Comment: As far as I'm aware there is not limit, but never confirmed, probably worth creating one parent record with 10,000 children using a bulk import just to test. I'm not sure there would be a documented answer to this question so worth experimenting.